# Transfer excel File in memoryStream to frontend corrupted

Tags: .net, angular

I use angular 7 with .NET 3.5 with C# for creating the `xlsx` file I am using openXML SDK.
I can't paste all the code because of the enterprise rules but know that the file is created properly when I save it on the server I don't have corruption

back end
I create my file who was working fine when I save it on the server

```
 MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
using (SpreadsheetDocument document = SpreadsheetDocument.Create(ms, SpreadsheetDocumentType.Workbook))
byte[] xlsxInBytes;
string xslxBase64;
```

my code to populate the file

the code to save it and put it on base 64

```
workbookPart.Workbook.Save();
xlsxInBytes = ms.ToArray();
xslxBase64 = Convert.ToBase64String(xlsxInBytes);
return Ok(xslxBase64);
```

front end

```
downloadFile(data: string, contentType: string) {
    // const contentType = 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet';
    const blob = new Blob([data], { type: contentType });
    // const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);

    // const test = atob(data);
    console.log(blob);
    const downloadLink = document.createElement('a');
    document.body.appendChild(downloadLink);
    downloadLink.href = 'data:application/' + contentType + ';base64, ' + encodeURI(blob.);
    downloadLink.download = 'title.xlsx';
    downloadLink.click();
    document.body.removeChild(downloadLink);
    // window.open(url);
  }
```

when I open the file it says it corrupted